# Sending info from python to pastebin

Tags: python, pastebin

I'm currently writing a script in which I am hoping a user will open and the system info from their pc will be uploaded to Pastebin

All info prints to the console but I have no clue how to get it to upload to Pastebin whenever someone opens the file

Any help would be great!

Im using this to get the info pasted to the console

````
from requests import get

ip = get('https://api.ipify.org').text
print('Ip address=: {}'.format(ip))
print("="*40, "System Information", "="*40)
uname = platform.uname()
print(f"System: {uname.system}")
print(f"Node Name: {uname.node}")
print(f"Release: {uname.release}")
print(f"Version: {uname.version}")
print(f"Machine: {uname.machine}")
print(f"Processor: {uname.processor}") ```
````

Comment: You have to use pastebin's API if any, to `POST` the data there and get a link

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, you have to first see if there's any API that pastebin provides. It looks like someone already created a [library for this](https://pypi.org/project/Pastebin/).

As per the docs:

1. Generate a key from your credentials

```
from pastebin import PastebinAPI
my_key = PastebinAPI.generate_user_key(api_dev_key, username, password)
print(my_key)
```

2. Use that key to create a new pastebin and get a link:

```
PastebinAPI.paste(api_dev_key, api_paste_code, api_user_key = None, paste_name = None, paste_format = None, paste_private = None, paste_expire_date = None)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, Ive tried installing Pastebin, however when i open Visual Studio Code and paste     ```from pastebin import PastebinAPI
my_key = PastebinAPI.generate_user_key(api_dev_key, username, password)
print(my_key)``` i get an undefined variable for "PastebinAPI" and for "(api_dev_key, username,password) Are you able to help me?

Comment: @Underscore do: `pip install pastebin`

Comment: Ahh this doesn't works, always throws this error : AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlopen'

Answer (score 0):

import the Pastebin module

The package allows you to communicate directly with Pastebin.com from your Python application, either logged in or anonymously. This can be handy

for a number of reasons - dumping error logs before an abort, regular web-based status updates, but can’t be bothered getting a web-server running, etc.

It allows you to do everything the API allows, which is:

- Paste, either logged in or anonymously
- 200+ selectable languages for syntax highlighting
- Set expiry times on pastes
- Set public/private/unlisted status for pastes
- See trending pastes
- See pastes by a particular user
- Delete your pastes
- Retrieve your user details
- Generate a session (user) key for added security
- Paste using the old, non-token anonymous API (for as long as they keep it open)

first use

```
    pip install Pastebin
```

and here is the reference documentation for more help.